# save checkbox sate of recylcerview in model

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Hey I like to save my checkboxstate of my ViewHolder in a Model, but when I switch the activity the state is not saved.

My ViewHolder:

```
  mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (int) compoundButton.getTag();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: position " + compoundButton.getTag());
                        mRecipe.get(getPosition).setSelected(compoundButton.isChecked());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + mRecipe.get(getPosition).isSelected());
```

My onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {

holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);

Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: isSelected?");

if(mRecipe.get(position).isSelected()) {
    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: true");
}else {
    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: false");
}
```

My log at the onBindViewHolder says every time false...

my Model:

```
public class Recipe {

private boolean selected;

public boolean isSelected() { return selected; }

public void setSelected(boolean selected) { this.selected = selected; }

}
```

my BottomNavigation

```
public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationViewEx viewEx){
    viewEx.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.ic_home:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class); //ACTIVITY_NUM = 0
                    context.startActivity(intent1);
                    CustomIntent.customType(context, "fadein-to-fadeout");
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_search:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class); // ACTIVITY_ NUM = 1
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
                    CustomIntent.customType(context, "fadein-to-fadeout");
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_cookbook:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, CookbookActivity.class); //ACTIVITY_NUM = 2
                    context.startActivity(intent3);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_shoppinglist:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, ShoppinglistActivity.class); // ACTIVITY_NUM = 3
                    context.startActivity(intent4);

                    break;
```

Comment: What do you mean by switch the activity?  When the device is rotated?

Comment: Like I go the homeactivity and then back to my RecyclerViewactivity....

Comment: Are you finishing `RecyclerViewactivity` before moving to other activity ?

Comment: yeah but when I rotaded the device it won't save too...

Comment: @KrishnaSharma When I move the Activities are onStop, should I finish the Activity? I tried it in onStop() but it dosen't work..

Comment: do you want your screen/activity data states should be maintain on orientation change ? 2) do you also want to finish RecyclerViewactivity while moving to other activity ?

Comment: for the 2nd point, if you simply launch the other activity and don't finish the RecyclerViewactivity then issue will not be there. once you finish other activity by pressing back button RecyclerViewactivity data states will be remain as it is

Comment: 1) yeah, I like the same state of checkbox when I change... 2) I dont' know I am really new in that :D

Comment: ah how do I avoid to finish my activity?

Comment: share your code where you launching other activity from recycler activity

Comment: Oh and what is when the user close the app?... Is my way right to save a checkbox state like this?

Comment: I change my activites with my BottomNavigation, I will share it. My ShoppingList is my "reycler activity"

Comment: If you are finishing your Activities and you want to preserve the state you'll need to persist the state in either SQLite db or SharedPreferences.  As for device rotation read through and understand how the Android Activity Lifecycle works, specifically Saving and restoring transient UI state - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras

Comment: I solved it with SharedPreferences - Thank you very much! :)